# finding an automorphism group of the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, automorphism-group, mobius-transformation

Can I find automorphism group of the domain $\mathbb{D} - a $ ? where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc with center 0 in the complex plane and $a$ is a point in $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: First step: Can you answer if $a = 0$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, is it true the group is collection of functions $f \in Aut(\mathbb{D})$ where $f(a)=a$?

Answer (score 3):

A holomorphic map of a punctured disk to itself is bounded (because the disk is bounded), so the isolated singularity at the puncture is removable. Thus, an automorphism of a punctured disk extends to an automorphism of the disk...

EDIT: with a single point missing from the disk, the extended automorphism must fix that point. The group of holomorphic automorphisms of the open disk is *transitive*, so without loss of generality the missing/fixed point is $0$. Then Schwarz inequality proves that the automorphisms of the disk fixing $0$ consist of rotations.

With two (or more) points missing, again send one to $0$, and then ask how many rotations fix a non-zero point. No non-trivial ones. So the group would be trivial...

Comment: so does not matter if we remove one point or two from the disc, right?

Comment: @math_for_ever, apparently not! :)

Comment: then how would the group look like on the domain $\mathbb{D}-\{a,b\}$?

Comment: Please, correct, "none" to "one."

Comment: @MoisheKohan, :) .

Comment: @paulgarrett I apologize if I'm misreading your last sentence, but are you stating that (for example) the automorphism group of the unit disk minus ${0,p}$ is trivial? This cannot be the case, as we can construct an biholomorphism of $\mathbb{D}-\{0,p\}$ which swaps the two punctures as such:
$$f(z)=-\frac{z-p}{1-\bar{p}z}$$  
which clearly extends to an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$.